# Get request works with postman/browser but not with code

Tags: node.js, axios, get, postman

I've developed a code that fetches stock data from the NASDAQ API. This script used to work perfectly, but one day it suddenly stopped working, and I'm consistently receiving a timeout error from the `axios.get` call.

Oddly, when I attempt to test the GET request using Postman or even through my web browser, I receive the expected results without any issues. To help diagnose the problem, I've made a few changes to the code.

Could someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Here is the code snippet, including the changes I made to investigate the problem:

```js
export const getOptionQuote = async (ticker, maxExpDate, maxStrikePrice, Optiontype) => {
    try {
        const today = new Date(Date.now());
        const todayStr = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];

        // Using this dynamic URL typically
        const url = `https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/${ticker}/option-chain?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=${todayStr}&todate=${maxExpDate}&excode=oprac&callput=${Optiontype}&money=out&type=all`;

        // This is an example URL with valid parameters (works in Postman)
        const url2 = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/GOOG/option-chain?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=2023-10-19&todate=2023-12-03&excode=oprac&callput=put&money=out&type=all';

        const res = await axios.get(url2);
        console.log(res);

        const rows = res.data?.data?.table?.rows || [];
        const currentPrice = parseFloat(res.data?.data?.lastTrade.split('$')[1].split('(')[0].trim());
        console.log('Got quotes');

        return [rows, currentPrice];
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Seems like this API doesn't work with axios for some strange reason but works fine with fetch(). Would you be willing to use the fetch() method included with node.js? (If you're on versions before Node 18, you'll have to install and use node-fetch instead).

Comment: No, I don't mind. 
but I  did try with node-fetch and It didn't work for me.

Comment: This is a very odd problem. It seems that fetch works just fine but node-fetch and axios don't. Maybe there's something on the server-side blocking these requests?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the API requires some headers for some reason. I'm not exactly sure how axios works, but here's a working example using node-fetch (you can also use regular fetch() in Node 18+).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const res = await fetch(url2, {
    headers: {
      "accept-language": "*",
      "user-agent": "node", // you may want to change this
    },
  });
```